# Automorphism Groups of Projective Algebraic Surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

When does a projective algebraic surface have an infinite automorphism group?  Is there a simple criterion, or at least a sufficient condition?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, let us start with a baby case. Consider a projective smooth **curve** $C$ over an algebraically closed field $K$. Let $T_C$ be the tangent bundle on $C$. The following facts are well known.

- If $C=\mathbb P^1$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(C)=\mathrm{PGL}(2,K)$ is an algebraic group of dimension $3$. On the other hand, $\dim_K H^0(C, T_C)=3$.
- If $C$ has genus $1$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(C)$  is an algebraic group whose connected component is $C$ (once an origin is chosen), hence has dimension $1$. On the other hand, $\dim_K H^0(C, T_C)=\dim_K H^0(C, O_C)=1$ ($T_C\cong O_C$ in this case).
- If $C$ has genus $g\ge 2$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(C)$ is a finite (algebraic) group, hence has dimension $0$. On the other hand $\dim_K H^0(C, T_C)=0$ because $\deg T_C=2-2g <0$.

In higher dimension the picture is a little more complicate. Let $X$ be a projective variety over $K$. The group $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is the points of a group scheme over $K$. This is proved using Hibert schemes and by viewing an automorphism as a closed subscheme of $X\times X$ via its graph. See e.g. the excellent book of Kollár, *"Rational curves on algebraic varieties"*, I.2.10. 
The group scheme is locally of finite type and the tangent space at the origin has dimension $\dim_K H^0(X, T_X)$ (Exercice I.2.16.4, use Thm I.2.16).

- 1st conclusion: if $K$ has characteristic $0$, as any group scheme locally of finite type is automatically smooth, the dimension of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is $\dim_K H^0(X, T_X)$. In positive characteristic, the former is bounded by the latter.
- In characteristic $0$, in order for the automorphisms group to be finite, $H^0(X, T_X)$ must vanish. The converse is not true because $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ can be a discrete infinite group.

This of course is not a very satisfactory answer to your question. But:

- If $X$ is of [general type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_dimension#General_type) (curves of general type are those of genus $\ge 2$), then $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is always finite. This results from a theorem of Kobayashi-Ochiai in characteristic zero (generalized by Deschamps-Ménégaux in positive characteristics). This theorem is a generalization to higher dimension of [de Franchis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Franchis_theorem) for morphisms of curves.

There is a lot of work (over $\mathbb C$) on the bound of the order of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ when $X$ is of general type. But this is another story.

Comment: So if the global sections of the tangent bundle have dimension n, then the automophism group is an algebraic group of dimension n?

Comment: Yes, you are essentially correct.

Comment: Nice answer, Cantlog.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's a bit late, I can't resist adding the following comment to Cantlog's excellent answer.

As mentioned there, looking at vector fields doesn't suffice, because there is the possibility that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ can be an infinite discrete group.

In the latter case, however, we can get some information by looking at the natural representation of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ on the Néron–Severi group $NS(X)_{\mathbf{R}}$ (meaning divisors on $X$ modulo numerical equivalence, tensored with the real numbers). The homomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(X) \rightarrow GL \left(NS(X)_{\mathbf{R}} \right)$ always has kernel an *algebraic group*, so in this case it will be finite. So the image will be an infinite subgroup of the general linear group.

Now there's a natural convex-geometric object acted on by $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ via this representation, namely the *cone of curves* $C(X)$ of $X$. A rational polyhedral cone which is fixed by an infinite subgroup of integer matrices cannot have finitely many extremal rays. So the conclusion is that if $C(X)$ has finitely many extremal rays, then $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ **cannot** be infinite discrete. This is useful because in practice, one can often calculate $C(X)$.